# How to prevent 100% width of <span> with "float: right;" content in IE6 & 7?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I have a dynamically generated form that displays fine in all browsers that I have tested except IE6 & 7. I have headings that should be able to be placed either above or to the side of the form inputs. For radio buttons and check boxes I want the control to the left of the label, for all other inputs I want the control to the right. The HTML should be the same for both, only the CSS should change.

```
() Radio 1  () Radio 2
[] Checkbox 1  [] Checkbox 2
Text |____________|
etc.
```

or

```
Radio 1  Radio 2
()       ()
Checkbox 1  Checkbox 2
[]          []
Text
|____________|
etc.
```

So far I've got

```
<span class="control">
  <label for="a1" class="forbutton">A1</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="a1" class="form-input-checkbox" name="a" value="1"/>
</span>
```

or something similar for each input. The CSS is

```
.forbutton {
  margin-bottom: 0.20em;
  float: right;
}
.control {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  position: relative;
}

/* Only if you want labels above inputs */
.form-input-checkbox,
.form-input-radio {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

In IE6 & 7 the <span>s end up being 100% width instead of taking the width of their content (as with the other browsers, including IE8). How can I fix this easily? If I give the span a width it does fix it, however, I don't know how wide it should be since the labels are dynamically generated.

Goals:
Valid HTML
Valid CSS
Labels before inputs in HTML code
Same HTML code for labels above and labels to the side

Any solution that achieves the same outcome will be gratefully accepted!

Comment: @CJDennis - I was thinking "LOL! But seriously" to the idea of people still trying to support IE6. Most developers I know were dropping IE6 support about two years ago. IE7 now has lower usage than IE6 had then, and IE6 itself has virtually disappeared from the web.

Comment: @Spudley These forms are going to be used internally in my company. No guarantee that older browsers aren't being used, and must work without changing users' browsers. I can't stop people from using bad browsers. If I could, IE would no longer be used in any form!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend getting rid of "display:inline-block" on that span. IE7 and earlier versions do not understand it. 
Additionally, the other styles that you have on that element, in this example, don't really warrant the use of inline-block. Span is inline by default, I would just leave it that way.

Comment: IE7 does understand `inline-block`. It has some serious bugs around it, but it does understand it, and it does work differently to `inline`.